# Different ways to declare LOOKAHEAD in JAVACC

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, javacc

I have been understanding Javacc grammar to write the parser where i found a line which tells like

```
Options : { LOOKAHEAD=3; }
```

I wondered what was the LOOKAHEAD and is there any different ways to declare the lookahead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LOOKAHEAD options is the default number of tokens that will be used to make a decision on which path will be chosen at each choice point.

This configuration is required to resolve choice conflicts as javacc does not support backtracking.

The default value for the `LOOKAHEAD` option is 1. So it is important to write the grammar that suits for LOOKAHEAD=1, meaning choices will be resolved by looking one token ahead.

For Example :

As the JavaCC is a LL parser, if the left token of a production rule is repeated,  a choice conflict will arise:

```
void PhoneNumber() : {} {​

(LocalNumber() | CountryNumber()) <EOF> ​

}​

void LocalNumber() : {} { ​

AreaCode() "-" <FOUR_DIGITS>  ​

}​

void CountryNumber() : {} {  ​

AreaCode() "-" <THREE_DIGIT> "-" <FOUR_DIGITS>   ​

}​

void AreaCode() : {} {   ​

 <THREE_DIGIT> ​

}
```

Note that both `CountryNumber` and `LocalNumber` start with terminal `<THREE_DIGIT>` which causes the choice conflict,

This can be rewritten by an approach called "left​ factoring​."

```
void PhoneNumber() : {} {​

AreaCode() "-" (LocalNumber() | CountryNumber()) <EOF> ​

}​

void LocalNumber() : {} { ​

<FOUR_DIGITS>  ​

}​

void CountryNumber() : {} {  ​

<THREE_DIGIT> "-" <FOUR_DIGITS>   ​

}​

void AreaCode() : {} {   ​

 <THREE_DIGIT> ​

}
```

For the case where this cannot be done, a Lookahead specification is used

Lookahead specifications are of five types as,

- Multiple token LOOKAHEAD
- Syntactic LOOKAHEAD
- Combination of Multiple token and Syntactic LOOKAHEAD​
- Semantic LOOKAHEAD
- Nested Lookahead

> Multiple token LOOKAHEAD

This can be used with the integer passed in the LOOKAHEAD(k) method. It can be done by,​

- Local LOOKAHEAD​

  void PhoneNumber() : {} {​
  (​
  LOOKAHEAD(3) LocalNumber() ​
  | CountryNumber()​
  )  ​
  }
- Global LOOKAHEAD​

  Options : { LOOKAHEAD=3; }

> Syntactic LOOKAHEAD

The Syntactic lookahead ​specification uses a syntactic construct as a choice resolver.

When specifying the syntactic​ lookahead without multiple token, what you're really​ specifying is syntactic lookahead with infinite multiple tokens.​

Eg: LOOKAHEAD(2147483647,​ LocalNumber())​

```
void PhoneNumber() : {} {​

(​
LOOKAHEAD(("A"|"B")+ AreaCode() "-" <FOUR_DIGITS>) LocalNumber() ​

| CountryNumber()​

) <EOF> ​

}
```

> Combination of Multiple token and Syntactic LOOKAHEAD

With this we could Lookahead ​a limited number of tokens as long as the syntactic lookahead satisfied within the specified choice will be made.

```
void PhoneNumber() : {} {​

(​
LOOKAHEAD(10, ("A"|"B")+ AreaCode() "-" <FOUR_DIGITS>) LocalNumber() ​

| CountryNumber()​

) <EOF> ​

}
```

​

> Semantic LOOKAHEAD

Semantic lookahead involves embedding a Java boolean expression in the grammar at the choice point.​

If boolean expression evaluates to true​, the current expansion is chosen.

```
void PhoneNumber() : {} {​

(​
LOOKAHEAD({getToken(1).image.equals("123")}) ​
KeysvilleNumber() ​

| FarmvilleNumber()​

) <EOF> ​

}
```

​

> Nested Lookahead

Nested lookahead occurs when​ one lookahead directive ​overlaps another.​
In JavaCC nested syntactic lookahead​ is ignored, but not the nested​ semantic lookahead.​

```
void Start() : {} {​

(​
LOOKAHEAD(Fullname()) Fullname() ​

| Douglas()​

) <EOF> ​

}​

void Fullname() : {} {​

( LOOKAHEAD(Douglas() Munro()) ​

 Douglas()​

| Douglas() Albert()​

)​

Munro() ​

}​

void Douglas() : {} { "Douglas" } ​

void Albert() : {} { "Albert" }}​

void Munro() : {} { "Munro" }}
```

*All the examples are taken from the Awesome book **Generating Parsers with JavaCC by Tom Copeland***

Hope this is useful, Thanks.

Comment: JavaCC creates top-down recursive descent parsers, which are LL, not LR. That explains both why LOOKAHEAD declarations are frequently necessary and why they are relatively easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the most advanced version of JavaCC is [JavaCC 21.](https://javacc.com/)

JavaCC21 offers a new way of specifying lookahead that is much more user-friendly and less error-prone than what there is in the legacy JavaCC project. I refer to the *up-to-here* delimiter.

If you have a production like:

```
void FooBar() : {}
{
   "foo" "bar" Baz()
}
```

and you want to scan ahead 2 tokens to see whether to enter a FooBar(), in legacy JavaCC, you write:

```
LOOKAHEAD(2) FooBar()
```

every time you use the FooBar() production. Or alternatively you could write:

```
LOOKAHEAD("foo" "bar") FooBar()
```

In JavaCC21, you can write the production as follows:

```
 void FooBar() : {}
 {
    "foo" "bar" =>|| Baz()
 }
```

The `=>||` is called the *up-to-here* delimiter and means that we scan up to this point. If you write the production as above, you can simply write:

```
 FooBar()
 |
 SomethingElse()
```

and the generated parser scans up to the point that is specified in the production when deciding whether to enter FooBar().

The *up-to-here* delimiter frequently allows you to express things in a much less cumbersome manner. For example, in the legacy tool, you would write maybe:

```
 LOOKAHEAD (Foo() Bar()) Foo() Bar() Baz()
```

while in JavaCC21, you can write:

```
 Foo() Bar() =>|| Baz()
```

JavaCC21 has an (optional) streamlined syntax as well, so you could write the above FooBar production more tersely as:

```
  FooBar : "foo" "bar" =>|| Baz ;
```

Of course, the *up-to-here" syntax is hardly the only new feature in JavaCC21 that is not present in the legacy tool. There is too much to outline here. A real biggie is that nested syntatic e]lookahead now works in JavaCC21. See [here.](https://javacc.com/2020/07/15/nested-syntactic-lookahead-works/)